# Actionbarsherlock ActionMode in Fragment Support

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

Trying to use startActionMode in fragment but got this error at

mMode = startActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions()); LINE 55

http://pastebin.com/d9jzg9UC

[image]

How to slove this? ActionMode not supported in Fragment?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to invoke an *instance* method of an Activity from a *static* Fragment (i.e. one that is separate from the instance of the Activity). Remembrer that you can always access the activity that contains your fragment using `getActivity()`. So:

```
  if (getActivity() != null) {
    mMode = getActivity().startActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());
  }
```

A cleaner approach would be to declare an interface class to manage the communication between fragments and activities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but before I post at SO, I did try `getActivity()` and also `Context` but of them both don't works, image : http://i.imgur.com/YRrCU.png

Comment: That's because you can't use "this" as an argument. You need to provide an instance of `ActionMode.Callback`, like in [this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_actionbar)

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActionMode(android.view.ActionMode.Callback)) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After hours of trying and searching. Found the answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12507967/1039582), need to use `getSherlockActivity()` can't use `getActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

in support library you can use it :

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode (new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());
```