# Sherlock ActionMode bugs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionmode

I've implemented `ActionMode` with `SherlockActionBar` and everything works fine, but only on devices post `HONEYCOMB`.

On older `APIs` I have the following problem:

Everything is fine when I start my app

[image]

All goes well even when I start action mode and select a couple of items

[image]

But when I exit (finish) action mode `ActionBarSherlock` crashes. I mean that it's no loger visible, only when I start or finish action mode, it blinks very shortly that I can see icons
[image]

So only updates show ActionBar for a short moment, but after that it remains "hidden" again.

Has anyone similar problem? Is there any sollution for that?

Comment: How did you make that `ActionMode`?

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12507967/1313175