# Compatiblity for Contextual ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat, contextual-action-bar

If we are providing compatibility for ContextualActionBar to a lower Android version,  should we fall back to a floating context menu on those devices(below Android 3.0) ?

is there no support from AppCompat Support Library from Google?

will ActionBarSherlock support ContextualActionBar in Lower Android devices?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Contextual Action Bar is supported in the Android Support Appcompat via [ActionBarActivity.startSupportActionMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#startSupportActionMode%28android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback%29)

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Quoting from the docs

Note: The contextual action mode is available on Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher and is the preferred technique for displaying contextual actions when available. If your app supports versions lower than 3.0 then you should fall back to a floating context menu on those devices.

[Android compatibility contextual action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538128/android-compatibility-contextual-action-bar)

Comment: will ActionBarSherlock support ContextualActionBar in Lower Android devices?

Comment: @saravanan yes check the second link

Comment: @saravanan check this http://theopentutorials.com/examples/android/listview/android-contextual-action-bar-for-listview-item-deletion-using-actionbarsherlock/